# Checking string length with strlen

Tags: php, strlen

I have this code, i want it to check if the length is **NOT** 32 or 40. The code below only checks if the word is 32 or 40 in length.

```
<?
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dgt']);
$len = strlen($name);
if (!($len == "32" or $len == "40")){
print "This is not a name.";
} else {
echo 'This is a name';
?>
```

Comment: if checking an integer (as is the case in `strlen`) even in PHP, don't check `int` values against their `string` equivalents, technically this is a logic error as `"32"` is checking for the string value of '32' and NOT the integer value of 32

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if ($len != 32 && $len != 40)`

try that out

Comment: Why are you wrapping an integer in quotes?

Comment: yeah, forgot to take off the quotes :) .. was going to mention not to check integers in quotes above :) .. thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
if($len != 32 and $len != 40)
```

Comment: It is a valid logical operator: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: @RUJordan - `and` is a valid conditional statement in PHP. So is `or`.

Comment: You test string!? `int strlen ( string $string )`

Test integer instead…

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dgt']);
$len = strlen($name);
if ($len != 32 && $len != 40){
print "This is not a name.";
} else {
echo 'This is a name';
?>
```